# The alias field of the Pydantic Model schema is by default in swagger instead of the original field

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I need to receive data from an external platform (cognito) that uses PascalCase, and the Pydantic model supports this through field aliases, adding an `alias_generator = to_camel` in the settings I make all fields have a PascalCase alias corresponding

In this way, the model:

```py
class AuthenticationResult(BaseModel):
    access_token: str
    expires_in: int
    token_type: str
    refresh_token: str
    id_token: str
    
    class Config:
        alias_generator = to_camel
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
```

it can receive the following dictionary without the slightest problem:

```py
data = {
  "AccessToken": "myToken",
  "ExpiresIn": 0,
  "TokenType": "string",
  "RefreshToken": "string",
  "IdToken": "string"
}
auth_data = AuthenticationResult(**data)

print(auth_data.access_token)
# Output: myToken
```

However, in the application's Swagger documentation it is also in `PascalCase` format, but it must return in `snake_case` format, which is strange, since `by_alias` is False by default.
Here's the format:

[image: Swagger Printscreen]

I need it to be in `snake_case` format to send it to the client. How can I do this, so that it continues to accept being built using a `PascalCase` dictionary

Comment: Did you get any solution to this? or what did you come up with?

Answer (score 2):

Might be easiest to create a sub model inheriting from your main model to set the alias generator on, then user that model for validation and the first one to generate the schema.